# Для каких целей в Python используются побитовые операции

Tags: python

Столкнулся с побитовыми операциями. Изучил побитовое сложение, конъюнкцию и дизъюнкцию. Таблицы истинности и все, что с этим связано. Но не нашел понятных примеров кода применения. 
Был бы признателен, если бы кто-нибудь привел пример понятного кода применения побитовых операций

Comment: https://pythoner.name/sets-operations

Comment: Действительно, это операции со множествами. Я подумал про побитовые операторы. И полез с ними разбираться. И появилось куча вопросов.

Comment: если на вход подавать биты - это будут побитовые операции, если подавать множества - то это операции над множествами.

Comment: Это понятно, я вопрос отредактировал.

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

```
FLAG_MATH = 0b001
FLAG_BIOL = 0b010
FLAG_CHEM = 0b100

student = FLAG_MATH | FLAG_BIOL & ~FLAG_CHEM       # 0b011 простейшее, но непонятное

if student & FLAG_MATH:
    print ("Сделал экзамен по математике.")
else:
    print ("Провалился на экзамене по математике.")
```

---

Вывод:

> Сделал экзамен по математике.

---

Объяснение:

Для студентов используем отдельные биты для отдельных предметов. Значение `1` значит, что он сделал экзамен, `0` - что провалился.

Теперь (см. `student = ...`):

- **включение** флага  (присвоение значения `1`) - оператор `|` с *маской*, в которой `1` на соответствующей позиции,
- **выключение** флага (присвоение значения `0`) - оператор `&` с *маской*, в которой `0` на соответствующей позиции,,
- **переключение** флага (`0` на `1`, `1` на `0`) - operator `^` с *маской*, в которой `1` на соответствующей позиции.

Тест:

- флаг **включенный**? - Оператор `&` с *маской*, в которой включен только соответствующий бит (т.е. все остальные `0`), например `0b001`, что в нашем примере `FLAG_MATH`:

  ```
  if student & FLAG_MATH:
  ```